# Why File.exists returns false positive

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I have a weird problem with my android File.exists functionality. Below is my code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_file_browser, container);

        DataBaseHelper tmpHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
        ButtonInfoContainer infoContainer = tmpHelper.getVideoWithId(videoId);



        //Tmp way to use this. When UX is finished will create a better way.
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/aslkfj");
        Log.i(StaticValues.TAG, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/aslkfj");

        LinearLayout tmpView2 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_recordings);
        if(f.exists());
        {
            Log.i(StaticValues.TAG, "f exists");

            String[] tmp = f.list();
            View tmpView = null;

            if(tmp != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i ++)
                {   
                    tmpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                    TextView tmpText = (TextView) tmpView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                    tmpText.setText(tmp[i]);
                    tmpView2.addView(tmpView);
                }
            }
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Everything is cool but the weird part is that File.exists returns a false positive for me. It always says that the file exists (just in this app though). the path given above /aslkfj does not exist but when I run this code my logcat outputs f exists. Why would something like that happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `semi-colon` at the end of your `if` condition: -

```
if(f.exists());  <-- Semi-colon here is causing problem
```

Due to this, the following block is just a local block, which will be executed regardless of what your if condition evaluate to.

Comment: Thanks, i cant believe I didn't notice it. It has happened once before and Im usually careful about it.

Comment: @Raigex.. Well, it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

You have a critical typo:

```
if(f.exists());
```

The `;` basically ignores the `if` statement.

This is very handy for quick conditionals like:

```
if(f.exists())
    Log.i(StaticValues.TAG, "f exists");
```

But an oopies here.